# How to build client control using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to build client component using javascript without jquery

Ex:

`div.load()`. It will show table on html page

Comment: Not clear. Please explain more

Comment: You need to explain your question, because as it stands there's no way of answering this without speculation and guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but if I've understood correctly I think you're looking for something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function MakeTable()
{
  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>my table</td></tr></table>";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad='MakeTable();'>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. You misunderstand my issue. I need build plugin client control using Javascript without jquery. The same jtable control, when you write obj.load() it will generate table with json data. I am researching about that. Sorry for my stupid question